# What can cause the working directory to be changed (if `Dir.chdir` is not called)?

Tags: ruby, chdir, pwd

I have a script that uses `Dir.getwd` to get the current working directory multiple times. Then it does things with it. This works for 99.9% of the users all of the time but for some users it returns an unexpected value in *some* cases. This causes an exception.

What can cause the working directory to be changed?

(`Dir.chdir` is not called at all in that code.)

---

Backstory:

I contribute to the open source [mobile automation command line tool *fastlane*](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane), which is written in ruby.

We have the problem, that a small number of users report `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)` errors being thrown [by a `File.join`](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/0338c9fb8103039a3a7390a5d02b9641d9e604d8/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/fastlane_folder.rb#L53), where one parameter is supplied by [a method `self.path` in the same file](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/0338c9fb8103039a3a7390a5d02b9641d9e604d8/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/fastlane_folder.rb#L8-L16).

`self.path` is trying to find out the path of some of our configuration by using `File.directory?` and `File.exist?`. Usually the first line `value ||= "./#{FOLDER_NAME}/" if File.directory?("./#{FOLDER_NAME}/")` in the method should "trigger" and set the value. This is how it works for 99.9% of our users.

For the remaining few, the use of this method works the first 1 or 2 times, then it gets wonky and returns unexpected values or none at all - as the method doesn't have a fallback it can return `nil` if none of the 6 conditions are met. But: These conditions are checking files that were not touched, and on the first invocation one of these conditions was definitely true (as it should be)!

(Unfortunately I can't reproduce the issue at all on my machines.)

Through [`puts` debugging via a branch and a discussion in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12789) ([branch is here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/13840/files#diff-b689c89143bd5d85e0a0fefd34aa2e85L9)) we could pin it down to the working directory changing in an unexpected way - multiple times. It goes from the `project_directory` where the script is executed, to `project_directory/fastlane` where the configuration lives, or the other way around.

That by itself would be ok, as the method is made exactly for these two cases. But the value seems to change from line to line of the code! (Here is a [comment on the GitHub issue](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12789#issuecomment-445370312) that shows how `Dir.getwd` suddenly returns other values) Because of this none the conditions can be met and we get `nil`.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I saw an issue where a specific Ruby version (2.3.3 iirc) broke on one of the path operations when $HOME wasnt set (which occurs inside AWS EB instances). Is everyone on the same version of Ruby? I wouldn't rule out an edge case behavior like that (that looks like a bug) but maybe that's a place to look (is it happening across multiple Ruby versions or platforms). PR where I noticed behavior: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/pull/330

Comment: The only other thing that jumps out with that block of code is the `||=`, which isn't thread safe (not 100% clear if you're using threads inside the scan call). I'd verify platform & ruby versions for people submitting the bugs. Also, I'd swap out these `||=` assignments for straight up early returns (e.g. `return "./" if <foo>`) in these lines: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/fastlane_folder.rb#L9-L14

Comment: I hadn't asked for environment information before, my impression was all macOS but different ruby versions. [Asked them now](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12789#issuecomment-445468662). Regarding the threads, this code is really at the beginning of the execution, not much has happened before. There is some Update checker being "spawned" before we get to this code, but I didn't find anything in there and disabling it had no effect.

Comment: I could probably neutralize this problem by e.g. using `return` instead of `||=`, caching the path instead of "recalculating" it by checking the file system  every time the method is called. That would definitely decrease the number of affected users, but the underlying problem would still exist - somehow the working directory is changing in strange ways. If I optimize it to only a few calls that interact with the FS, instead of the hundreds we have right now, those few can still fail and crash the script :/

Comment: If you can post a link to a sample repo & the command(s) to run and (try to) reproduce, I wouldn't mind taking a deeper dive into the ruby side of things. I setup a sample xcode project and ran the fastlane command but couldn't get the kind of output you were showing in your github issue. So, I'm not sure I was using the fastlane command correctly, or didn't have the right kind of project set up.

Comment: Installing fastlane, setting it up in a project and to use a Gemfile and then running `bundle exec fastlane scan` causes the problem for some people. Here are the instructions for my debugging branch with all the added output: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/12789#issuecomment-444942320 Unfortunately it can't be reproduce reliably, even people encountering have to try multiple times.